# Classification for a special simple group

Tags: gr.group-theory

The prime graph of finite group $G$, is as follows: the vertex set is prime
divisor of $|G|$ and two distinct vertices $p$ and $q$ are joined by an edge
if and only if $G$ has an element of order $pq$. Let $G$ be a simple group
such that $|G|\mid q(q^{2}-1)/2$ where $q=p^{n}$, $p$ is prime ($p\mid |G|$). Let the number of
connected components of prime graph $G$ are at least $2$ ( $p$ is an isolated
vertex).

My question: Is there any classification for such group $G$?

Comment: I am a bit puzzled. Any integer $m$ divides $q-1$ for a suitable $q=p^m$. So, the class of simple groups $G$ such that $Card(G)$ divides $q(q^2-1)/2$ is the class of all simple groups. You do not assume that $p$ divides the order of $G$, so can this question be phrased purely in terms of a simple group $G$?  

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://books.google.com/books?id=UA-YqrL58dQC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=Williams,+Prime+graph+components+of+finite+groups&source=bl&ots=2J_GbjUsWz&sig=IpI7OFbla981IHLQDTKQyClhhSg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wmbaT5XGEouc8gSsmNGNBA&sqi=2&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Williams%252C%2520Prime%2520graph%2520components%2520of%2520finite%2520groups&f=false) should give you what you're looking for along with orders for the groups listed.